# How to find integer values $a,b$ and $c$ such that $a^3+b^3+c^3 =30$?

Tags: number-theory

**Question** :

> How to find integer values $a,b$ and $c$ such that  $a^3+b^3+c^3 =30$?

Comment: What does this have to do with linear algebra? Are you seeking integer solutions to $a^3+b^3+c^3=30$?

Comment: Can $a, b, c$ be negative?

Comment: yeah sorry..i’m new to this..i’ll edit the tag..

Comment: yes..negative numbers come under intergers right? @arthur

Comment: $30=2220422932^3 + (-2218888517)^3 + (-283059965)^3$, look [here](https://ckrao.wordpress.com/2012/04/10/integers-equal-to-the-sum-of-three-cubes/).

Comment: @ProfessorVector From your links (https://arxiv.org/pdf/1604.07746.pdf) this second solution is also reported; $30 = (−662037799708799)^3+ 190809268841284^3+ 656711689254565^3$

Comment: Gives any values to a then you solve the remain equation

Comment: @Guy Fsone ,  certainly not!

Comment: @ Professor Vector , this result deserves to be known; write an answer.

Comment: Negative numbers are usually part of the integers, yes, but it's an easy error to make, and it is the difference between this problem easily having no solutions to this problem being _difficult_. See https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wymmCdLdPvM, for instance

Comment: Based upon comments, this question should be reopened to allow posting of answers in said comments.